# Flutter dio cannot go to the interceptor when it call

Tags: flutter, dio

I tried refreshing my tokens when my calling api goes to error 401 (token expires) but when it calls dio interceptor is not triggered.

api.dart is definition of my dio

```
Dio _createHttpClient() {
final api = Dio(
new BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: environments.api,
  contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
  responseType: ResponseType.json,
  ),
);
api
..interceptors.clear()
..interceptors.add(new ErrorDialogInterceptor())
..interceptors.add(new AuthTokenInterceptor(api));


return api;
}

final api = _createHttpClient();
```

profil_provider.dart is the call of my api

```
Future<ProfilePicture?> getPictureProfile(String id) async {
String url = '/v1/users/$id/profile-picture';

try {
  final response = await api.get(
    url,
    options: Options(
      responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
      headers: {
        ErrorDialogInterceptor.skipHeader: true,
      },
    ),
  );
  Uint8List avatar = Uint8List.fromList(response.data);
  return ProfilePicture(image: avatar);
} catch (e) {
   print('e');
  return null;
  }
}
```

and it go to the catch error

auth_interceptor.dart is for manage my error and request of my api

```
class AuthTokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {
static const skipHeader = 'skipAuthToken';

Dio api;

AuthTokenInterceptor(this.api);

@override
onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
 final context = applicationKey.currentContext;
 print("test");

final repository = context?.read<AuthRepository>();

if (repository == null) {
  return;
}

final accessToken = await repository.getAccessToken();
print("access: $accessToken");

if (accessToken != null) {
  print(accessToken);
  options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
}

 return super.onRequest(options, handler);
}

@override
onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
final context = applicationKey.currentContext;

if (context == null) {
  return;
}

final response = err.response?.data;

if (response == null) {
  return super.onError(err, handler);
}

final repository = context.read<AuthRepository>();

if (err.response?.statusCode == 401)
if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 &&
    await repository.getRefreshToken() != null) {
  api.interceptors.clear();
  return _handlerRefreshToken(context, repository, err, handler);
}



return super.onError(err, handler);
}
```

and it not go to the auth interceptor with my debug print, I don't know why it not go there with the error 401 from the catch error

Answer (score 0):

you can do.

```
// returns the http request
Future<Response<ProfilePicture>> getPictureProfile(String id) {
   String url = '/v1/users/$id/profile-picture';
   return api.get(url)
}

//...

// and use a try/catch outside the method
try{
   Response<ProfilePicture> respose = await getPictureProfile(555)
   print(respose.data)
}catch(e){
   print(e)
}
```